# not getting Pushsharp notification after new Updates by iOS

Tags: ios, xamarin, push-notification, pushsharp

I'm trying to implement PushSharp manually sending push from my backend server with my Xamarin Project. It is working fine before Apple updated some config.
P12 policy updated : https://developer.apple.com/news/?id=12172015b)?

We changed our code as per PushSharp new code done in 3.0 dev branch. After that we are not getting any exception in backend side code, but we are also not getting Notifications.

So please help us to solve this.